# Prestashop 1.7 hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra is not working?

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using the hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra hook. It's work 1.6 prestashop version. But for 1.7 don't work.

Here is the my codes

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params)
{
    $this->smarty;

    $id_product  = Tools::getValue('id_product');

    $get_values = $this->getProductCurrencyRow($id_product);
    $this->smarty->assign('get_values',$get_values);
    $this->smarty->assign('id_product',$id_product);

    $currencies = $this->getDefaultRates();
    $this->smarty->assign('currencies',$currencies);

    return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/admin/productcurrency.tpl');
}
```

This codes working for prestshop 1.6 here is a screenshoot from 1.6
[image]

But when i install the my plugin prestashop version 1.7 i have a some problems about Admin Products Extra hook here is a screenshot from 1.7

[image]

New tab is come to module options name and its not hear the product options menu. hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra is changed new version? How can i fix

Thanks.

Comment: But why use the version 1.7? Yes, they say that is stable and usable, but it doesn't, trust me...

Comment: I just want to make my module stable for 1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PrestaShop 1.7 they have changed the logic for hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra hook, now all the modules using this hook will be displayed in a single tab named 'Module Options' instead of a separate tab for each module. That means you can't show a separate tab for your module in PrestaShop 1.7

For more details about the hooks in PrestaShop you can visit the following link:

http://build.prestashop.com/news/module-development-changes-in-17/

Answer (score -1):

Simple:

```
public function hookdisplayProductExtraContent($params)
{        
    $array = array();
    $array[] = (new PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Product\ProductExtraContent())
            ->setTitle('tittle')
            ->setContent('content'));
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: This hook is used for extra product content on the front-office, not the back-office